# error field.add by powershell 0x80004005

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

why facing error ?

line: $list.Fields.Add("test", $spFieldType, $false) - give error

i tried add new column (type - url ) via code :

powershell :

```
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin>
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $web = Get-SPWeb "http://localhost/Task"
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $list = $web.Lists["test"]
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin>
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $spFieldType=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::URL
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $list.Fields.Add("test", $spFieldType, $false)
Исключение при вызове "Add" с "3" аргументами: "Не удалось завершить эту операцию.
Повторите попытку."
строка:1 знак:17
+ $list.Fields.Add <<<< ("test", $spFieldType, $false);
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $View = $web.GetViewFromUrl("Lists/List1/AllItems.aspx")
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $Field =$List.Fields["test"]
PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $View.ViewFields.Add($Field)
Исключение при вызове "Add" с "1" аргументами: "В экземпляре объекта не задана    ссылка   на объект."
строка:1 знак:21
+ $View.ViewFields.Add <<<< ($Field)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

 PS C:\Users\zabiyakin> $View.Update()
```

thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (only I'm not using the `Get-Web` cmdlet):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$url = "http://localhost/Task" 
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)   
$web= $site.openWeb();

$list = $web.lists["test"];

$spFieldType=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::URL 
$list.fields.add("test", $spFieldType, $false);
```